# npm install subdirectories using gnu parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am trying to install a set of sub-directories from the parent dir using GNU `parallel`.

I'd like to run certain commands for all directories.

Installing

```
ls -d -- */ | grep -v 'node_modules' | parallel "npm i"
```

Removing `node_modules`

```
ls -d -- */ | grep -v 'node_modules' | parallel "rm -rf node_modules"
```

Create `README.md`

```
ls -d -- */ | grep -v 'node_modules' | parallel "touch README.md"
```

How can I fire the first argument of parallel as a command within each directory passed to `parallel`?

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -d -- */ | grep -v 'node_modules' | parallel "cd {} && npm i"
```