# Run script command on parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i’ve bash script which I need to run on it two command in parallel

For example I’m executing a command of npm install which takes some time (20 -50 secs)

and I run it on two different folders in sequence first npm install on books folder and the second
is for orders folder, is there a way to run both in parallel in shell script ?

For example assume the script is like following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

   dir=$(pwd)

  cd $tmpDir/books/  

  npm install

  grunt

  npm prune production 
  cd $tmpDir/orders/

  npm install

  grunt

 npm prune production
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967908/npm-install-subdirectories-using-gnu-parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `&` to run the process in the background, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd $HOME/project/books/
npm install &

cd $HOME/project/orders/
npm install &

# if want to wait for the processes to finish
wait
```

To run and wait for nested/multiple processes you could use a subshell `()` for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

(sleep 10 && echo 10 && sleep 1 && echo 1) &

cd $HOME/project/books/
(npm install && grunt && npm prune production ) &

cd $HOME/project/orders/
(npm install && grunt && npm prune production ) &

# waiting ...
wait
```

In this case, notice the that the commands are within `()` and using `&&` that means that only the right side will be evaluated if the left size succeeds (exit 0) so for the example:

```
(sleep 10 && echo 10 && sleep 1 && echo 1) &
```

- It creates a subshell putting things between `()`
- runs `sleep 10` and if succeeds `&&` then runs `echo 10`, if succeeds `&&` then run `sleep 1` and if succeeds `&&` then runs `echo 1`
- run all this in the background by ending the command with `&`

Comment: You should add the "wait" keyword then to make the script to wait for all of its child processes before moving on

Comment: Thanks 1+ ,  in case I run for each folder `npm install` and then `grunt` and then `npm prone production`  I should do it for each and it will start one after one there will be no collusion ?

Comment: @JennyHilton I updated the answer, hope can give you some ideas

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try it now and let you know! :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need,btw  it can be done only like this `(npm install && grunt && npm prune production ) &`  ? I ask it since im generating this script and I want to put comment between the commands ....

Comment: any comment to my comments question ?

Comment: @JennyHilton you can add comments above/below the line, but inline would not work